# python отслеживание ввода русских букв

Tags: python-3.x, клавиатура

Такой код запускаю под sudo в ubuntu 20.04

```
import keyboard
  
translate = {
    'down':' нажал на клавишу ',
    'up':' отпустил клавишу '
}


def print_pressed_keys(e):
    print(vars(e))


keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

при нажатии на русской раскладке в консоли получаю латинские символы

```
й{'event_type': 'up', 'scan_code': 16, 'time': 1620406491.093332, 'device': '/dev/input/event3', 'is_keypad': False, 'modifiers': (), 'name': 'q'}
```

как в `e.name` получить русские буквы?

Comment: Подозреваю, что эта библиотека отслеживает именно нажатие клавиш на клавиатуре, а не вводимые символы. А клавиши то нажимаются одни и те же, не важно какой язык включен.

Comment: если CrazyElf прав, то я вам порекомендую воспользоваться мультиплатформенной библиотекой [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/). Она обрабатывает нажатия клавиш, с учётом языка.

Comment: pynput import keyboard
  
результат тот же, нажимаю й получаю {'vk': 113, 'char': 'q', 'is_dead': False, 'combining': None, '_symbol': None}